# Displaying Strings on frame with drawString?

Tags: java, user-interface, paintcomponent, drawstring

So my program is like this, I click a part of the frame and a JOptionPane comes out, asking for input. For example, I type in APPLES. Then, I click on another part of the frame, this time typing in ORANGES.

Here's the catch. When I hover over the points I clicked, for example on the point of APPLES, APPLES in the form of a drawString will appear on the frame. Then when I hover over ORANGES point, ORANGES should appear.

I would like to have different Strings displayed on my frame upon hover. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance! :)

Note: No need to bother with the mouseListeners and mouseMotionListeners, my only problem is displaying the various strings via drawString :) or you can recommend other alternatives.

Comment: Assuming you're overriding `paint(...)` why don't you just check some condition whether to draw a string or not based on the mouse coordinates?

Comment: Oops sorry. I misread your question. That's the problem. I don't know how to match the coordinate with the String.

Comment: What is the problem to implement and register `MouseMotionListener` to react to `mouseMoved()`

Comment: @korifey Sorry? I didn't get your question.

Comment: I want to tell that you can listen for mouse motion events and when mouse hover of some place (bounding box of your 'string'), paint whatever you need by paintComponent() method

Comment: @korifey Yeah I already know that :) What I want to know is, how can I connect the point of my click to the String I have inputted and DRAW the right String on my drawString?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, I understood your problem right. But you have to override paintComponent(Graphics g) method in your form class, and in this method you will call g.drawString(yourString); method. and when you hover over your "apple point" , just set "yourString" on "APPLES and call method repaint() of your frame class. Don't forget to clear the area of your form, so the strings are not at each other over.

Comment: Um. I do not want to initialize the String. It can be any String. For example, I type any word in the optionpane, it must correspond with the point and display the word I have entered.

Comment: So you have to use some kind of data structure ( like ArrayList, HashMap or whatever) for storing your Point-String pairs, and when moving you're mouse, just find apropriate string of the Point, you moved over and set yourString to found string.

Comment: I have actually implemented a HashMap already, however, what it's doing is it's displaying the same String for every point D: